# How can I instantiate a generic container such as List<T> where T is specified in config in C# 4.0?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have an application in which I would like to define message queues in config. So I would like to specify in config some number of message types such as "app.msg.UpdateMsg" or "app.msg.SnapshotMsg" for which to create queues.

Say my message queue class looks like this:

```
public class MsgQueue<T> : where T: MsgBase, new()
{
    private readonly Action<T> _queueListener;

    public MsgQueue(Action<T> queueListener)
    {
        _queueListener = queueListener;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now let's say I have another class that wants to read from config the queue types listed there, and put them into a container. Something like this:

```
public class QueueManager
{
    // We know T is a MsgBase, but not much else :(
    private List<MsgQueue<MsgBase>> _msgQueues = new List<MsgQueue<MsgBase>>();

    public QueueManager()
    {
        List<string> configuredQueueTypes = GetQueueTypesFromConfig();

        PopulateMsgQueues(configuredQueueTypes);
    }

    private void PopulateMsgQueues(List<string> qTypes)
    {
        foreach (string qType in qTypes)
        {
            Action<MsgBase> listener = GetListener(qType);

            // What goes here? How do I create a MsgQueue<qType>?
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

How do I define PopulateMsgQueues(), if that's even possible?

Is it possible (and would it help) if I could specify in config something like "app.MsgQueue of app.msg.UpdateMsg"?

Does anyone know of any other way to instantiate a bunch of MsgQueue of T where T is specified by a string at runtime?

I'm using C# 4.0, so can the dynamic keyword help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Type.GetType(string)` and then use that to instantiate your generic class.

For example, this would instantiate a list of strings:

```
Type type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("String"));
Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Check the example I gave. You lose strong typing, but that may or may not be a concern.

Comment: I want to create a MsgQueue<type>, not a List<type>. MsgQueue<type> has a constructor that takes an argument of Action<type>.

Comment: To be more like his example, you'd use `MsgQueue` instead of `List` and also `Activator.CreateInstance` can take constructor parameters.

Comment: CreateInstance returns an object, so I have to cast it to MsgQueue<MsgBase> to insert it into my collection of queues. Even so, the CreateInstance fails with: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'MsgQueue`1[[PublishMsg, QueueEngine, Version=1.43.101.17649, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dynamic is good here. You'll need to resort to good old reflection.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, because the type needs to be known at compile time, not runtime.

You can use reflection, but you lose the strong-typing and there's a performance hit (which may or may not matter to you)

```
Action<MsgBase> listener = GetListener(qType);
Type type = typeof(MsgQueue<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("String"));
dynamic msgQueue = Activator.CreateInstance(type, listener);
//do whatever with msgQueue.
```

Comment: How would I use reflection? Performance is of no consequence to me, as queues are only created during startup in my case.

Comment: @OmniJeff see my updated answer.  You won't get intellisense but you should be able to call methods on the queue normally with `dynamic`.

Comment: OK, I got it to work, but the trouble was in `Activator.CreateInstance(type, listener)`. I simplified my problem case a bit by omitting the fact that the MsgQueue constructor actually has a couple more args in it and they are base classes and interfaces. C# is too dumb to find the constructor to use when there are base classes or interfaces in play when using `Activator`. When I use `var ctorInfo = type.GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(Action<T>)})` it of course works. Thanks for trying to help!